# In tableau how to show unmatched row in my case?

Tags: tableau-api

I'm new to tableau.

I have a data like this.

[department]

[image]

[employee]

[image]

And I want to get employee count under 30 age per department. like this..

[my goal]

[image]

I want to show all departments (if there is no employee)

To get result, I do these steps,

- make relationship of `dept - emp` (one datasource)
- make datasource filter (emp.age < 30)
- make sheet and set row as `dept_no, countd(emp_no)`

But I could only get like this.

[my result]

[image]

How can I get my goal..!!??
Help me!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is simple hereafter.  Use join (instead of relationship) on the side of dept table and Take dept_no column from dept_table instead of emp_table.  To do this follow these steps

- double click on first added table (say emp).  A join window will open (thgis differs from relationship)
- add dept table and use right join

[image]

- right click `age` convert to dimension
- right click again `age` and convert to continuous
- create filter `at most` 29 on age and don't forget to check include null values in the table

[image]

- If you want to add all values in view.  create a calc field with calculation as

```
INT([Age] <30)
```

- add sum of this field to view

[image]

- edit the calculation to show all nulls as `0`

```
ZN(INT([Age] <30))
```

[image]

Comment: Very helpful! thanks. I got the result that I want. And I assume that dimension filter is like `HAVING` clause in sql and datasource filter is like `WHERE` clause in sql.

Comment: Glad to have been of help. Please upvote if you haven't already.  You are correct in dimension and measure (nit data source) filter